# Twentyfifteen style author comment

Tags: php, css

I am using twentyfifteen and I have made a child theme. I am trying to style author comments differently than visitor comment.

In other words I want the author replies to have a black background.

After searching the web for hours I give up and came here. Most of the tutorials I have found are for older themes which is written differently from twentyfifteen.

Please help me out if you can. Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are CSS classes for styling...

```
comment-author-admin bypostauthor
```

For (your) example:

```
.commentlist .byuser {background-color: black;}
.commentlist li ul.children li.byuser {border-top: 10px solid #e18728;}
```

Comment: `byuser`  if the comment was made by a registered user, then adds class "byuser" and "comment-author-" + the user_nicename sanitized (i.e. spaces removed). Also, if the comment is by the original author of the post, the class `bypostauthor` is added.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using `.comment.bypostauthor{}` in the stylesheet and it worked. After 5 hours I can finally breathe!